# where to change translationFallback to true in symfony 2 doctrine translatable

Tags: symfony, doctrine, translation, listener

I need to switch 'translation fallback' and 'persistDefaultLocaleTranslation' on.
I know how to change it: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#default-locale
but don't know where should I access that listener.. Maybe in config.yml? how??

I am looking for something like this:
(config.yml)

```
...
translatable-extension:
    translationFallback:true
    persistDefaultLocaleTranslation: true
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle installed (https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle), you can configure the default values for this in config.yml

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: "%locale%"
    translation_fallback: true
    persist_default_translation: true
```

Haven't found this is in any docs, but it is in the configuration for the bundle https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L30

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are asking but in a typical setup you would have the translation fallback referenced in your config.yml like this.

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
```

In this example the locale placeholder references the locale setting in your parameters.ini/parameters.yml file.

I believe this is commented out by default in your config.yml but uncommenting this line will effectively enable translations.

You can see the full list of configuration options with along with their defaults here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#full-default-configuration